# Rigorous treatment of blackbody radiation

Tags: thermal-radiation

I cannot understand the logic behind treating each normal mode of an electromagnetic radiation as a harmonic oscillator in the treatment of blackbody radiation. What do I need to know to treat it rigorously? Do I need quantum/classical field theory?